# How can I solve this limit involving $1/\sqrt{n^2+2n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have this limit but I cant solve it. I think that it is possible to solve with Stolz, but I can't see how.

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{n²+2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n²+4}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n²+6}} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n²+2n}}\right]$$

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps consider a Riemann sum?

Comment: Either you forgot the term $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+6}}$ or $2n$ should be $2^n$...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See that

$${n\over\sqrt{n^2+2n}}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n²+2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n²+4}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n²+6}} + \dots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n²+2n}} \le {n\over\sqrt{n^2+2}}$$

And the limits of both ${n\over\sqrt{n^2+2n}}$ and ${n\over\sqrt{n^2+2}}$ is $1$.

Therefore your limit is $1$.

Comment: and why $\frac{n}{sqrt(n²+2n)} >=sumofall$?

Comment: You can also use $n^2\le n^2+2k\le (n+1)^2$, so your sum is between $\frac{n}{n+1}$ and $\frac{n}{n}$...

Comment: @eslop It isn't, it is less than the sum of all because all terms are greater than the first one, and there are $n$ terms

Comment: @EricTowers Yes but $n\times \text{[smallest term]} \le \text{[sum of all terms]} \le n\times \text{[greatest term]}$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \root{n^{2} + 2k}} & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over \root{n^{2} + 2k + 2}} =
{1 \over \root{2}}\,\lim_{n \to \infty}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over \bracks{k + \pars{n^{2}+ 2}/2}^{1/2}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over \root{2}}\,\lim_{n \to \infty}
\bracks{\Phi\pars{1^{-},{1 \over 2},{n^{2} + 2 \over 2}} -
\Phi\pars{1^{-},{1 \over 2},{n^{2} + 2 \over 2} + n}}
\end{align}
where we used a [Lerch Zeta Function $\ds{\Phi}$ identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function#Identities).
$\ds{\Phi\pars{1^{-},s,a}}$ satisfies the
[asymptotic expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function#Integral_representations):
$$
\Phi\pars{1^{-},s,a} \sim {1 \over \pars{s - 1}\, a^{s - 1}}\quad\mbox{as}\quad a \to \infty 
$$

---

Then,
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}{1 \over \root{n^{2} + 2k}} & =
{1 \over \root{2}}\,\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{%
-2\root{n^{2} + 2 \over 2} + 2\root{{n^{2} + 2 \over 2} + n}}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{\root{n^{2} + 2n + 2} - \root{n^{2} + 2}}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}{2 \over \root{1 + 2/n + 2/n^{2}} + \root{1 + 2/n^{2}}} =
\bbx{\ds{1}}
\end{align}